# Data read during Scheduler with priority preemptive or round robin policy

Tags: operating-system, kernel, scheduler

If the scheduling policy is Priority Preemptive or Round Robin.

### Assuming i have created a dev-file through which i can directly access 256mb of raw data of a hardware device.

Let there be user process P1.

In this, i am continuosly reading 256mb data 4kb wise into user-buffer of 4kb.( Overwriting )

Can the following case can occur.

1.Trying to read the data from user space.

2.The Kernel driver tries to get data from the device .Which may take undeterministic time .(Let T1 be the time)

3.Then tries to copy into the buffer pointing the user-buffer.

4.During T1 , A new high priority process P2 preempted process P1.

5.Now when Kernel tries to put the data into the buffer. This buffer doesn't belong to P2's address space.

So will i get DATA Abort Exceptions or some kind of Error at undeterministic times ?

Comment: In short, in the case of Linux kernel, copiing to user space is performed at P1 time, and **cannot be preempted**. If you read file, content of block device is firstly read into in-kernel buffer, and copiing to user space uses this intermediate buffer, so it may be performed syncrhonously. It is possible to read data from block device *directly* into user space, but user space uses specially mapped area for that purpose. This area is allocated by the kernel, which uses its **kernel address** for copy data. That address isn't changed with switching user processes.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev. What if it is like vxWorks.Here there is no intermediate buffer . If i am trying to get 4kb contents from a  char-kind of device file , who's write call directly assign value from the device address to the buffer . Can this cause data abort now ?

Comment: I know a little about vxWorks and its implementation. As it is **real-time** OS, reading device file probably uses time of P1, and it cannot be preempted by another process. But it is just a guess.